# copying mutex from Parent to Child process

Tags: fork, parent-child, mutex

When we make child process which is clone of the parent process

There have been used mutexes under parent process...

Can mutexes be copied to child process?

If yes whats the disadvantage of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is defined in the process memory the current value will be set but it will not get updated by the parent process since the memory between the process is not shared.

You can share mutex between process as long as it is allocated in shared memory and has access by both process. 
[pthread_mutexattr_setpshared](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html)

You can also use named process semaphore or even unnamed process [semaphore](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2007/05/24/semaphores-in-linux.html?page=5) in case you fork, this will free you from allocating shared memory between the process, since semaphore are system-wide and remain in the form of files on the filesystem.

Comment: !careful! The fork example for unnamed semaphore in the second link you gave is wrong and won't work. The unnamed semaphore is copied to the child process, and not shared, see here: http://blog.superpat.com/2010/07/14/semaphores-on-linux-sem_init-vs-sem_open/